# change BarButton item identifier on code

Tags: ios

I have a bar button item on StoryBoard,its identifier is Play,
How can I change this bar button's identifier on code?

```
- (IBAction)play:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
  // For example,when I touch this button,
  // it change its Identifier to Stop
}
```

Comment: why you want to do that, I am not getting your point Leo

Comment: the Identifier is a property on storyboard,you can drag a Bar Button Item on storyboard,when I change the Identifier,the icon also change.What I don't know is how to change that property on code,because I can't find something like that in API

Answer (score 0):

use `UIButton`'s `tag` features

using `UIButton` outlet set tag for play like `testButton.tag = 1;`

then in

```
- (IBAction)play:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
       testButton.tag = 2;
    } else if (sender.tag == 2) {
       testButton.tag = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The tag maybe not work for my need ,Identifier is a property on storyboard,you can drag a Bar Button Item on storyboard,when I change the Identifier,the icon of the item also change.What I don't know is how to change that property on code,because I can't find something like that in API

Comment: Do you know that you can drag UIButton in Bar Button Item?